# What is the correct way to pass a std::vector to be a parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, reference-wrapper

I want to pass the a vector filled with object based same class.
Both `std::reference_wrapper` and no-reference do not fix it.
What's the correct way to solve this?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int){};
    virtual void print() const {
        std::cout<<"MyClass"<<std::endl;
    }
};
class MySubClass : public MyClass
{
public:
    MySubClass(int a):MyClass(a){};
    virtual void print() const {
        std::cout<<"MySubClass"<<std::endl;
    }
};
void test(const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MyClass>>& v)
{
    for (const auto& c : v) {
        c.get().print();
    }
}
void test(const std::vector<MyClass>& v)
{
    for (const auto& c : v) {
        c.print();
    }
}
int main() 
{
    {
        MySubClass s(2);
        std::vector<MyClass> v;
        v.push_back(s);
        test(v);//print MyClass, but I need MySubClass
    }
    {
        MySubClass s(2);
        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MyClass>> v;
        v.push_back(s);
        test(v);//print MySubClass
        test({2});
        test({s});//wrong ambigious
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `const std::vector<MyClass>& v` - There is no copy of `MyClass` here since you are passing a reference to the vector.

Comment: You're comparing apples to motorbikes -- do you want a vector of references or a vector of objects?  They have completely different uses.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Holt  Sorry, I didn't make it clear enough. Now I re-edited.

Comment: @ChrisDodd  Sorry, I didn't make it clear enough. Now I re-edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    MySubClass s(2);
    std::vector<MyClass> v;
    v.push_back(s);
    test(v);//print MyClass, but I need MySubClass
}
```

The problem here is that you're attempting to store `MySubClass` objects in a vector of `MyClass`. It is not possible to store the entire `MySubClass`, instead only the `MyClass` parent subobject is stored. This conflicts with your desire to treat the stored objects as if they were `MySubClass` instances.

```
{
    MySubClass s(2);
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MyClass>> v;
    v.push_back(s);
```

This solves the previous problem. References can refer to a subclass of their static type. Although, keep in mind that the object is not stored in the vector. The object is stored as a local variable `s` and only referenced by the vector.

```
    test(v);//print MySubClass
    test({2});
    test({s});//wrong ambigious
```

The problem here is that you have two overloads, of which neither accept a `MySubClass`, but both accept something that can be initialized from an initialization list of `MySubClass`. Therefore the overload resolution is abiguous. The compiler doesn't know which overload you intended to call.

Either use explicit temporary initialization instead of a plain initializion list.

```
    test(std::vector<MyClass>{2});
    test(std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MyClass>>{s});
```

Or don't use overloads, but uniquely named functions instead.

```
void test(const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MyClass>>& v)
void test2(const std::vector<MyClass>& v)
```

Comment: The OP might also want to consider `std::vector<const MyClass*>`.  It has very similar behaviour to the reference_wrapper version, but may be conceptually simpler for readers of the code.

Comment: @MartinBonner However, pointer may lose `test({2})` this convenient grammer.

Comment: @Ringo_D : Right.  If that syntax is useful to you, then pointers are less attractive.  (For many applications it won't be.)